# C++ Operator Overload and String Concetanation

Tags: c++

I designed a String class (I know there is already one)
Something like:

```
class String{
private:
char * str;
int size;
public:
String();
String(const String&);
String(char[]);
friend String operator+(const String&, const String&);

char* getStr() const {
    return str;
}


};
```

This is the code for operator+:

```
String operator+(const String& str1, const String& str2){

  String s(str1); //got a copy constructor, didn't put here, and this works, this is not the problem.
  s.size=str1.size+str2.size+1; //+1 for null character at the end, not sure if necessary here, keeping the size like this is also not used anywhere...
  strcat(s.str,str2.str);
  return s;
}
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What doesn't work? and where is the code that allocates some memory to hold your string? e.g: `str = new char[size]`

Comment: How much memory does the copy constructor allocate with `String s(str1);`? Please post a minimal part of it as this is relevant.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Mohamad, thanks. I totally missed memory allocation. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your code couldn't possibly be correct.

```
String s(str1);
```

This allocates memory, but doesn't know about the size of `str2`.

```
strcat(s.str,str2.str);
```

Now you append `str2` to it.

You have to allocate enough space. Writing beyond allocated memory is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed memory allocation. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to show the code that allocates the memory pointed by `s.str`. However, it's easy enough to guess that you didn't allocate enough.

The solution is to allocate at least `s.size` long array.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed memory allocation. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I just can guess, what exactly your problem is. I see multiple issues here:

1. You'll have to make sure, that you have allocated enough memory in `s.str`, before you call `strcat()`
2. You should avoid `fiend` like the plaque. Either implement your operators as member functions or have them use the public interface.
3. In don't know the reason, why you implement your own string class. Just don't do it. Chances are, that you won't remotely be able to make it better than `std::string` in any way.

I am a professional developer for roughly twenty years now and have been a hobbyist before for roughly twelve years. I have worked on many very different projects in many different companies with very different needs. I exactly had an issue that would justify a custom string class zero times. In my opinion, you should treat the standard library as part of the language and not try and reinvent the wheel, but a square one this time.

Comment: I know I don't need to implement my own String class as I cannot ever complete it myself. Strings are just good to work with pointers, memory allocation and I'm trying to learn operator overloading. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I totally missed memory allocation. Thanks everyone. This is my new operator+ function:

```
String operator+(const String& str1, const String& str2){
String s;
s.size=str1.size+str2.size+1;
s.str=new char[s.size];
strcat(s.str,str1.str);
strcat(s.str,str2.str);
return s;
}
```